# How to Deserialize Complex JSON file in SSIS into few columns

Tags: json, sql-server, ssis, deserialization

I have a JSON file that is pretty complex. Here is a snippet of my file:

### JSON

```
"SKU": "12345", 
"Status": {
    "Health": "OK"
}, 
"Type": "ComputerSystem", 
"Name": "Cartridge 1", 
"Power": "Off", 
"AssetTag": "12345", 
"HostCorrelation": {
    "IPAddress": [], 
    "HostMACAddress": [
        "00:00:00:00:00:00", 
        "11:11:11:11:11:11"
    ]
}, 
"SerialNumber": "12345", 
"Boot": {
    "BootSourceOverrideSupported": [
        "None", 
        "PXE", 
        "HDD", 
        "iSCSI", 
        "M.2", 
        "None"
    ], 
    "BootSourceOverrideTarget": "PXE", 
    "BootSourceOverrideEnabled": "Continuous"
}
```

Without showing all the classes here is the RootObject VS generates as code:

### Paste JSON as Class

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Power { get; set; }
    public string AssetTag { get; set; }
    public Hostcorrelation HostCorrelation { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public Boot Boot { get; set; }
    public Links links { get; set; }
    public string UUID { get; set; }
    public Bios Bios { get; set; }
    public Oem Oem { get; set; }
    public Memory Memory { get; set; }
    public Availableaction[] AvailableActions { get; set; }
    public string SystemType { get; set; }
    public Processors Processors { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
}
```

I want to loop through multiple JSON files with this structure, and put them into a few columns such as (Section, Component, Property, and Value).
However, I have been having a hard time figuring this out. It would be simple to put each part into its own unique column.

The end result of my JSON example above may look like:

### Goal SQL Output

[image]

The format doesn't have to be exact, but something along those lines. If there is a better way of doing this I am all ears.

Comment: Not possible: You can only match objects to rows in a table if each property can be mapped to a column there. However, the IP addresses or MAC addresses don't, because they have a variable length. They'd have to be stored in a different table with links connecting the relevant rows.

Comment: So if I make unique column for each, could I unpivot the data after to get it in the desired format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you didn't post all of your classes because the RootObject has object references, but this is how you could start your code. This won;t get your data into the format you asked for, but it is how the serializer works.

```
string json =  [Somehow get your json in to a string]   
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var jRow = js.Deserialize<Rootobject>(json);

// now you have your entire JSON in one object.

//for the data you presented you will need a few outputs:
// let's start with the outermost:

Output0Buffer.AddRow();
Output0Buffer.SKU  = jRow.SKU;
Output0Buffer.Health = jRow.Status.Health; //There is only one option here
Output0Buffer.Type  = jRow.Type  ;
Output0Buffer.Name = jRow.Name;
Output0Buffer.Power = jRow.Power ;
Output0Buffer.AssetTag = jRow.AssetTag ;
Output0Buffer.SerialNumber = jRow.SerialNumber ;
Output0Buffer.BootSourceOverrideTarget= jRow.Boot.BootSourceOverrideTarget ;
Output0Buffer.BootSourceOverrideEnabled= jRow.Boot.BootSourceOverrideEnabled;

//this is a new output of boot details linked by SKU
foreach(var dtl in jRow.Boot.BootSourceOverrideSupported)
{
     OutputBootStuffBuffer.AddRow();
     OutputBootStuffBuffer.SKU = JRow.SKU; //Making assumption that SKU is the key back
     OutputBootStuffBuffer.BootSourceOverrideSupported = dtl.BootSourceOverrideSupported;
}
```

Comment: I just typed this so there might be typos.

Comment: I thought I made it clear in my question that I didn't post all the classes, just the references. all together it would be too much code to put in one question. Thank you for this example though. It seems like a huge help. Also why did you mix SKU with the Boot?

Comment: I was looking at what seemed like the overall key for the subclass. Whatever the foreign key should be replaced with SKU

Comment: It would actually be Serial Number, but thank you I understand now.